# How to detect the x position of an object as we pan in react native?

Tags: react-native

I am trying to have 3 container, like an accordion one container shall be opened and other 2 is collapsed. Now I want the pan gesture to reveal/hide the containers as well as interpolated the neighbour container. Any tip is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
onPanResponderMove: (e, gesture) => {
    console.log('LocationXY --> X: ', Math.round(e.nativeEvent.pageX), ', Y: ', Math.round(e.nativeEvent.pageY)
},
```

Every time when you interact with object (in you case container) you have list of accessible events. For example onPanResponderStart/onPanResponderEnd/onPanResponderRelease/onPanResponderMove/etc. Full list of events you can find here (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/panresponder). What you need is **onPanResponderMove**. In example above `onPanResponderMove: (e, gesture)` you need  to focus attention on **e**, what means **event** (you can call it whatever you want). It is an object which contains whole bunch of information about an event. So just debugg an event (you can even start not with **e.nativeEvent.pageX**, start with **e**) and look for what you need.
But don't forget, that onPanResponderMove have to return some action with your object. For now your object will stay on the same place, thats why you need to add some animation, something like this:

```
onPanResponderMove: (e, gesture) => {
   let mover = Animated.event([ null, { dy: this.state.pan.y, dx: this.state.pan.x }]);
   console.log('E: ', e, ', Gesture: ', gesture) 
   return mover(e, gesture) ;
}
```

Now every time when you interact with object you will get full information about event in console and your object animation (you can place **mover** outside the onPanResponderMove).

Comment: Please comment your code and/or offer details and an explanation of how this solves the posted question.

Comment: @RyanNerd, I've tried to add simple explanation, but I think it's not really clear.